# Jquery custom Object parameter in Firefox (dynamic Navigation load dynamic content)

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox

Sorry I need your Help again :-(

I have made a Navigation with Main und Sub navigation. The sub menu will be shown or hidden automatically, depending on the click tab/link in the main menu.

The active state changes by the menstr value.

In IE it works perfect :-) in Firefox it does nothing :-(

I think the problem is the custom object attributes from the `<a>` tag that Firefox can't handle ?

Here is my code with comments:

Main level:

```
  <ul>
  <li><a id="M1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1:Sub1:S2" href="start1.php">Start1</a></li>
  <li><a id="M2" data-remote="true" menstr="M2:0:S0" href="start2.php">Start2</a></li>
  </ul>
```

Sub level:

```
<div id="Sub1" class="subv"  style="display:none">
<ul>
<li><a id="S1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1:Sub1:S1" href="sub1.php">Sub1</a></li>
<li><a id="S2" data-remote="true" menstr="M1:Sub1:S2" href="sub2.php">Sub2</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

**menstr:**

So menstr gives the actual state on the Navigation.

M1 to Mx = the active main tab (M1 is the first tab in the main bar)

Sub1 to Subx = the name on the sub navigation (0 = no sub bar)

S1 to Sx = The active Sub Tab

jQuery / Java at bottom of the page:

```
 <script>

 // Look if <a> is clicked and data-remote is true
 $('a[data-remote]').click(function(e) {

 // Prevent Default Action
 e.preventDefault()

  //Remove activ state/class from all Main Tabs
 $('.active').removeClass('active');

 //Remove active state/class from all Sub Tabs
 $('.sub_nav_active').removeClass('sub_nav_active');

 //Hide the Sub Tab
 $('.subv').hide();

 // Get and split the menstr
 var $menstr = this.menstr.split(':');

 //Set Main tab active
 $('#' + $menstr[0]).addClass('active');

 //Set Sub tab active
 $('#' + $menstr[2]).addClass('sub_nav_active');

//Show Sub div if some is there
$('#' + $menstr[1]).show();

// Load the content of href in the main div
$('#main').load(this.href);

});
</script>
```

I think one solution is give the menstr string inside the href but I think its not nice ...

The second problem I think is without data-remote I need to identify the links to handle with a class but I need it for the active state ...

THANK YOU VERY MUCH its a real great community :-)

Comment: try changing... var $menstr = this.menstr.split(':');  to  var $menstr = $(this).attr('menstr').split(':');

Comment: hey.. if i posted this an answer.. would you accept it.. just asking cuz.. i need some reputations..

Comment: Sorry i write one but write this as a answer and make a commend that every body who will see the working script may look at my answer i will accept it so you have given me the right hint !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

no problem Phantom001... your code is working fine.. and i was fiddling with it.. you can get a nice sub menu effect if you nest your submenus like this...   [jsFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/Sr5Qe/2/)

```
<ul>
<li>
     <a id="M1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S2" href="start1.php">Start1</a>
    <div id="Sub1" class="subv"  style="display:none">
       <ul>
       <li><a id="S1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S1" href="sub1.php">Sub1</a></li>
       <li><a id="S2" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S2" href="sub2.php">Sub2</a></li>
     </ul>
     </div>
</li>

 <li>
<a id="M2" data-remote="true" menstr="M2#Sub2#X1" href="start2.php">Start2</a>


  <div id="Sub2" class="subv"  style="display:none">
 <ul>
   <li><a id="X1" data-remote="true" menstr="M2#Sub2#X1" href="sub3.php">Sub3</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
     </li>

     </li>

 </ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Psych Half for the Hint !

I have made 2 changes now it works perfect in IE and Firefox.

I think its a small and lightweight dynamic navigation it load dynamic content and can handle infinite sub navigation if you need it.

If anyone need some like this:

(Css is your part ...)

- `.active` = Css class for the active Main tab
- `.sub_nav_active` = Css class for the active Sub tab

The rest is normal CSS styling ...

Main level Nav:

```
 <ul>
 <li><a id="M1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S2" href="start1.php">Start1</a></li>
 <li><a id="M2" data-remote="true" menstr="M2#0#S0" href="start2.php">Start2</a></li>
 </ul>
```

Sub level Nav (here Sub of M1):
(Make many as you want or add more values to the menstr string for a sub under sub)

```
 <div id="Sub1" class="subv"  style="display:none">
 <ul>
 <li><a id="S1" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S1" href="sub1.php">Sub1</a></li>
 <li><a id="S2" data-remote="true" menstr="M1#Sub1#S2" href="sub2.php">Sub2</a></li>
 </ul>
 </div>
```

menstr:

So menstr gives the actual state auf the Navigation.

M1 to Mx = The active Main Tab (M1 ist the first tab in the main bar)

Sub1 to Subx = The Name auf the sub navigation (0 = no sub bar)

S1 to Sx = The active Sub Tab

jQuery / Java at bottom of the Page:

```
 <script>

 // Look if <a> is clicked and data-remote is true
 $('a[data-remote]').click(function(e) {

 // Prevent Default Action
 e.preventDefault()

 //Remove activ state/class from all Main Tabs
 $('.active').removeClass('active');

//Remove activ state/class from all Sub Tabs
$('.sub_nav_active').removeClass('sub_nav_active');

 //Hide the Sub Tab
 $('.subv').hide();

 // Get and split the menstr
 var $menstr = $(this).attr('menstr').split('#');

 //Set Main tab active
 $('#' + $menstr[0]).addClass('active');

 //Set Sub tab active
 $('#' + $menstr[2]).addClass('sub_nav_active');

//Show Sub div if some is there
$('#' + $menstr[1]).show();

// Load the content of href in the main div
$('#main').load(this.href);

});
</script>
```

If anyone has questions or need help please ask.

Thanks to the Community :-)